# Debian - Broken package cannot be installed or removed

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I have an HP Microserver (Gen8) running Debian Jessie. When I first set it up, I installed the optional HP daemons to see what benefit they gave. One, `hp-health`, interfaces with the onboard iLO controller. I have since disabled the iLO because it requires a license to do anything useful, and I have no need of it. However, this has caused problems - the `hp-health` package now will not update, and when trying to remove it, I get the following:

```
root@NAS:/home/gargravarr# dpkg --force-all -P hp-health
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
(Reading database ... 47028 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing hp-health (10.40-1815.49) ...
  Trying to identify the Product Name...  
  ERROR: This server is NOT supported!
  Error: No supported management controller found
invoke-rc.d: initscript hp-health, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package hp-health (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
  Trying to identify the Product Name...  
  ERROR: This server is NOT supported!
  Error: No supported management controller found
invoke-rc.d: initscript hp-health, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status     1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hp-health
```

From the dpkg log, it seems like the init script is running hardware checks, failing to detect the iLO and determining it cannot run, thereby returning 1 to the calling command. Unfortunately, this means dpkg receives the exit code. Re-enabling the iLO controller means going into the BIOS and I am not able to do that. Instead, I tried adding an `exit 0` into the init script immediately before the standard `case` statement, but this seems to have done nothing. It's interfering with other package upgrades so it really needs to be uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was a bit hasty. As I wrote the question, I realised the init script must be performing the hardware checks before the case statement, so I looked back over it and found where the actual hardware check was done, added an `exit 0` there and sure enough the next run of `dpkg -P` succeeded. I'll mark the question as answered and leave it up in case anyone else encounters similar problems.